# What does "M" value mean for ceramic capacitors like: 226M 473M 107M?

Tags: capacitor, ceramic

For example:

- 22uF 16V 226M
- 47uF 10V 476K

What does this last specification mean?

Comment: that's part of what datasheets are for.

Comment: i would love datasheets in every part i buy ,but that is available only if you are in America with those electronic suplier sites. for almost all the rest of the world the smaller sites  or local stores or marketplaces almost never have datasheets. most of the times we dont even know what is the manufacturer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *what means that M value for ceramic capacitors like: 226M 473M 107M*

This might help: -

[image]

Image from [here](http://my.execpc.com/%7Eendlr/markings.html). Or maybe this: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.bragitoff.com/2015/09/capacitor-codes-explained/).

Comment: perfect, so, the letter is just the tolerance rate. good to know